# Split parameter into string variables

Tags: c#, regex, string, facebook-graph-api

I sent facebook a web request, it displays this on the screen,

access_token=129858573723395|2.AQB8yp6_GcD5hfxp.3600.1308506400.1-100000676383590|DUjbM8aN5PP-qzkLfTkGiZeCaLx4&expires=6099

How do I split it so that I have two variables access_token and expires.

access_token should have the value 129858573723395|2.AQB8yp6_GcD5hfxp.3600.1308506400.1-100000676383590|DUjbM8aN5PP-qzkLfTkGiZeCaLx4

expires should have the value 6099.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string response = "access_token=129858573723395|2.AQB8yp6_GcD5hfxp.3600.1308506400.1-100000676383590|DUjbM8aN5PP-qzkLfTkGiZeCaLx4&expires=6099";
string token = response.Split('&')[0].Split('=')[1];
Console.WriteLine(token);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx). It might require you to add the assembly System.Web.dll to your project references.

Most other solutions won't work properly if the string contains some characters encoded.

Answer (score 0):

`(.+?)=(.+?)(?:&|$)` will capture the key=value pairing for you.